# How Do I Perform A Transpose To A Mailmerge?

Tags: ms-access, vba

**EDIT: I Have figured out what I needed and placed the new portions of code in asterisks**

I am using VBA in Access 2003 and have the following question:

I have some code that does a mailmerge to create labels, and it works fine on its own. I have been asked to see if it is possible to have the labels run down the cells and then across. Right now they fill up across then run down to the next row. If it is possible, would it be best to do it before the mailmerge executes, or do I do it in the loop that I have following the mailmerge? It is very important that the "5660 EasyPeel Address Labels" formatting stays the same. I have placed my coding below.

```
With oDoc.MailMerge
With .Fields
    .Add oApp.Selection.Range, "FullAddress"
    oApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
End With
    Set oAutoText = oApp.NormalTemplate.AutoTextEntries.Add("MyLabelLayout", oDoc.Content)
    oDoc.Content.Delete

    .MainDocumentType = wdMailingLabels
    .OpenDataSource Name:=strTxtFile, ConfirmConversions:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False



    oApp.MailingLabel.CreateNewDocument Name:="5660 Easy Peel Address Labels", Address:="", Autotext:="MyLabelLayout"
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .Execute

    oAutoText.Delete

    'Loop through and add cell padding to each table.
            intTblCount = oApp.ActiveDocument.Tables.Count

            Do Until intTblCount = 0

                DoEvents

                oApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(intTblCount).TopPadding = PixelsToPoints(5, True)

                DoEvents

                oApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(intTblCount).Range.Select
                With Selection
                    .Font.Size = 9
                    .Font.Name = "Janson Text LT Std"
                    .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = LinesToPoints(0.8)
                    .ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 5
                    .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 5
                    .MoveRight wdCharacter, 5
                End With

                ***Call TransposeTable***
                DoEvents

                intTblCount = intTblCount - 1

            Loop
End With

***    Sub TransposeTable() 'Edited Sub from the Sub Written By Helmut Weber, MVP WordVBA

Dim C As Long ' column
Dim R As Long ' row

Dim x As Long ' just a counter
Dim y As Long ' just a counter
Dim z As Long ' just a counter
'Dim d As Long ' just a counter

Dim STempo As String
Dim sArr() As String

Dim NoGoArray As Variant: NoGoArray = Array(2, 4, 7, 9, 12, 14, 17, 19, 22, 24, 27, 29, 32, 34, 37, 39, 42, 44, 47, 49)

With Selection
    .Collapse

    With .Tables(1)
        C = .Columns.Count
        R = .Rows.Count

    ReDim sArr(1 To .Range.Cells.Count)
    For x = 1 To UBound(sArr)

            If IsInArray(x, NoGoArray) Then
                GoTo LoopContinue
            Else
                STempo = .Range.Cells(x).Range.Text
                STempo = Left(STempo, (Len(STempo) - 2))
                sArr(x) = STempo
                'GoTo LoopContinue
            End If

LoopContinue:
    Next

'--------------------------
' Transpose Table Content
'--------------------------
    C = .Columns.Count
    R = .Rows.Count
    x = 0
    For y = 1 To C
        For z = 1 To R
            If IsOdd(y) Then
                x = x + 1
                If IsInArray(x, NoGoArray) Then
                    x = x + 1
                    .Cell(z, y).Range.Text = sArr(x)
                Else
                    .Cell(z, y).Range.Text = sArr(x)
                End If
            End If

        Next
    Next
    End With
End With

Erase NoGoArray
End Sub

Public Function IsOdd(ByVal Number As Long) As Boolean
    IsOdd = (Number Mod 2 = 1)
End Function

Private Function IsInArray(valToBeFound As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
'DEVELOPER: Ryan Wells (wellsr.com)
'DESCRIPTION: Function to check if a value is in an array of values
'INPUT: Pass the function a value to search for and an array of values of any data type.
'OUTPUT: True if is in array, false otherwise
Dim element As Variant
On Error GoTo IsInArrayError: 'array is empty
    For Each element In arr
        If element = valToBeFound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next element
Exit Function
IsInArrayError:
On Error GoTo 0
IsInArray = False
End Function    ***
```

Comment: Of note, inside of the TransposeTable Sub, the NoGoArray has an array of numbers that correspond to the cell position of cells that need to be skipped for the Avery 5660 line of labels. If you are using a different style of labels, your numbers will vary.